# regex to get portion of file name after last dot without file extension

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of files, some examples are as follows:

```
/foo1/foo2/bar1.bar2.bar3.answer.jar

/foo1/bar1.bar2.answer.jar

/foo1/foo2/answer.jar
```

and for all of the above I would like a regex that matches 'answer'.  In other words, I'm looking to get an alias for the file that is the portion of the file name after the last dot (or the file name itself if there are no dots) with the file extension (.jar can be guaranteed here to make it simpler) stripped off.

I know I can do this with a more simple regex to split the value up by dots and then get the second last one, but in this case I'm building a back-end thing that will ideally take a regex that is defined in a configuration definition for the given file type, and spit out the alias, which might be different for other file types.

Yep, I'm over-engineering.  :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following regex should work for you:

```
[^/.]+(?=\.jar$)
```

If using Javascript or a similar flavor where `/` is regex delimiter then you need to escape `/` like this:

```
[^\/.]+(?=\.jar$)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regexp: (assuming that the answer part doesn't contain `.` or `/`)

```
[/\.]([^/\.]+)\.jar
```

The first capturing group is the part what you want to.

Comment: It fails when input is `'answer.jar'`